# How to convert PHP code to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a beginner for codeigniter, could you help me to convert this PHP code to codeigniter please?

```
$kuerimatpel = "SELECT id_matpel from matpel 
                where id_matpel order by bobot desc, nama_matpel  asc";


if ($querymatpel = mysqli_query($con, $kuerimatpel)){
    if (mysqli_num_rows($querymatpel)>0){
        while($matpel = mysqli_fetch_array($querymatpel)){ 
                 $arraymatpel1[]= $matpel['id_matpel'];
            }
        }
    } 

foreach ($arraymatpel1 as $keymatpel => $value) {   
    $matpelid = $arraymatpel1[$keymatpel];
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you:**

**Note** : *make sure you have configure you db setting in `database.php` and load database either in `autoload.php` or in controller*

like In `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Do like this :  *(for more help go to the below link)*

```
$id_matpel = 'value for where condition';
$this->db->select('id_matpel');
$this->db->from('matpel');
$this->db->where('id_matpel',$id_matpel);
$this->db->order_by('bobot','DESC');
$this->db->order_by('nama_matpel','ASC');

$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
   $arraymatpel1 = $query->result_array();
}
/* print here to check for data 
  print_r($arraymatpel1);
*/
foreach ($arraymatpel1 as $key => $arrmatpel) 
{  
   /* do whatever you want*/
   $matpelid = $arrmatpel['id_matpel'];
}
```

for reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html